# Speed of the usual approximation of the exponential

Tags: exponential-function, approximation

Let's consider the usual approximation of the exponential function $f_n(x)=(1+\frac{x}n)^n$.

What do we know about its speed of convergence to the exponential? That is to say, how can we characterize the functions $g_n(x)=|f_n(x)-e^x|$ and $h_x(n\in\Bbb{N})=|f_n(x)-e^x|$ ?

(Context: I am working on other approximations of the exponential, and I would like to compare those to the usual approximation of the exponential without simply looking at graphs)

Comment: It's very slow: you get $f_n(1)=2.7$ for $n=74$, $2.71$ for $n=164$ and $2.718$ for $n=4822$!

Comment: @Bernard I know, but since I'm looking at $\left(1+\frac{x}{2^n}\right)^{2^n}$ in my research, it converges much faster.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540982/error-analysis-of-exponential-function?rq=1.